# How to Encrypt External Hard Drive so It Can be accessible only from XBMC on Raspberry PI

Tags: raspbmc, kodi, password

I have an external 1TB USB hard drive linked to a Raspbmc setup (XBMC on Raspberry Pi), Currently the files (pictures, music, movies) on this drive are naked, so anyone can copy or delete them if he attached the drive to his laptop.

I want to password protect my files on this drive so it could not be copied however Raspbmc should able to access the files somehow, is there a way to set a password in XBMC to read password protected drives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Logical Volume Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) (LVM) to create a logical volume on the HDD.  You can then use [dm-crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt) to encrypt your LVM.

Archlinux has great documentation on [Disk Encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_Encryption) and [Encrypted LVMs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Encrypted_LVM).  I highly recommend these open-source options over TrueCrypt.

If you want the pi to be able to access the information easily, you may want to use a file instead of a passphrase for decryption.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is going to be TrueCrypt, or something like that.  Encrypt the volume, and only mount it when you want to use the disk.

I don't think you will find the solution you want already written but in an open source world, I'm sure it can be done... That would be a pretty cool expansion for XBMC.